# Inconveniente con Simultaneidad optimista en C#

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Cordial saludo, espero se encuentren bien quiero pedirle el favor si me puede colaborar con lo siguiente, estoy realizando la actualizacion de un registro utilizando EntityDataFramework en C# con Sql server como aparece en el minuto 58:00 del video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uM1IWOWEUw4&t=2s) lutilizando la instrucción (DB.Entry(modelo).State = EntityState.Modified;) , el error que me aparece es referente a algo que se llama simultaneidad optimista que dice (Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected numbers of rows(0).Entities may have action been modified or delete since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.) ,para ello he visto códigos de la página :http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540,pero de todos esos códigos al implementarlos en mi desarrollo nada sirven, el código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
 private void Modificar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try {
                modelo.IdCliente = int.Parse(txtIdcliente.Text);
                modelo.Nombres = txtNombres.Text.Trim();
                modelo.Apellidos = txtApellidos.Text.Trim();
                modelo.Dirección = txtDireccion.Text.Trim();

                using (PruebaZiurSoftwareEntities DB = new 
 PruebaZiurSoftwareEntities())
                   {
                   DB.Entry(modelo).State=EntityState.Modified;
                    DB.SaveChanges();
                  
                }
                clear();// Una vez guardado que vacie los textos
                llenarGrid();
                MessageBox.Show("Los registros se han actualizado satisfactoriamente!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 

            }
        }
```

Gracias por su colaboración que me pueda brindar. para solucionar dicho inconveniente.

Comment: Creo que sin código de ejemplo no podremos hacer mucho.

Comment: Hola Arriel ya incluí el código, saludos!